# vuejs set a layout in js and run that in template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Title sounds a bit weird but let me explain.

I made a component that allows me to generate dynamic input fields based on a json list.

Only some fields I would like to have next to each other and that is not possible in the current construction. So I came up with an idea to make a JSON "layout template" with rows and columns and which ID field belongs where.
For example "layout template":

```
{
 "row": {
   field: {id:"ID-FIELD-1",type:"text"}
 },
 "row": {
   field: {id:"ID-FIELD-2",type:"phone"},
   field: {id:"ID-FIELD-3",type:"email"}
 },
 "row": {
   field: {id:"ID-FIELD-4",type:"text"}
 }
 etc...
}
```

Now I can make a JSON "layout template" and put an "input component" in each field. This "input component" then loops to the correct type of input field. Only this seems a bit too much to go through the input list every time looking for the right type for each field.

So I've been looking for ways in javascript to setup/format the whole template in a "string" like way and have it picked up by Vuejs as if it were a standard ....
Then I dont have to loop the whole field section every time.

I don't know if this is possible or if there are other ways to do this?

Comment: Why not loop the whole thing? Seems straightforward and simple.

Comment: Here's a very simple example: https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9Uk1PwzAM/Ssml4K0tmJwqjYkpIGYxJ3DzGGs6ZbRJlHiDqaq/x2nHa3QNHJJ/PGeX2w34tHa5FBLkYmZ3zhlCbyk2j6gVpU1jqABJwtooXCmgohTI9SoN0Z7gspvYR7i19GLLEsDb8aV+VV0M6Y48+U5Z4Ua+DT9BaDyDCKOxbfRJPiQkAoly9xnsGo4imK5iJ+XT6+L+BbFhI5Wso/kN6Fo3xkSEG2HHVgH0mlPyucS53TktDujJZNOmOhv0t2YJKu1Ks8rI51qI50V/+9L95e/FLBszNJ+HDwINkhWtlyTZAtglqsDHOLCuDkKrghKd21GAdmnPPbOROUounQGKG1rGiCdqBMo6RWO0M7uwJAFhYMrGOxMewkpa+DXLB2UiYnoNyau1jbZe6N5p7ru4CnAVbLfWaHgTQo2ih2R9Vma+mITNnHvE+O2Kb8SV2tSlUykr+KP8EPpmBhFoOA+taL9ATL25OU=

Comment: @RobLouie Thank you, this will definitely help me forward. I try to loop as little as possible. Because the forms can be quite long and this can have a performance impact. Again Thank you very much.